# Rename tag medieval-china

Tags: discussion, retagging

[medieval-china](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval-china) doesn't make sense: there is no Medieval / Middle Ages period for China. For the timespan covered (221 BC to 1912 AD), I would prefer [imperial-china](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imperial-china). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_China) also uses this terminology.

Comment: Medieval China is usually placed somewhere between the Han and Song dynasties, e.g. the Kyoto School. Even the most expansive version I've seen, i.e. Bai Shouyi's *General History*, dates the end of China's Middle Ages to no latter than 1840, which has become the consensus start date for Modern China. So not really an exact overlap with imperial china.